# Redirect http, non-www to https, with www for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I tried almost all the solutions I can founded in stackoverflow and other websites, but I can't get it work, so I tried to submit my question.

My folder will be:

- `public_html/wordpress root folder` (A)
- `public_html/wordpress root folder/traveltour` (B)

I've installed Let's Encrypt to (A) and it works for (B) without installing Let's Encrypt again in (B). But I can't redirect (B) to HTTPS with www. Some of the code I've tried in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

```
#force https 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And more when I found it via Google search, but nothing works. I hope get some advices to resolve it with `.htaccess` without use plugin, that's why I posted my question here and not at WordPress StackExchange.

---

### Edit:

If I tried load: (B) with http & non www, it's stay to http with www, or if I tried load: (B) with http & with www, it's stay same with no https. Some of code redirect (B) to (A) and made my link 404 not found, so I've removed it out.

---

### Edit 2:

I have individual `.htaccess` file and the director structure like below:

- `/public_html/.htaccess` (A)
- `/public_html/B/.htaccess` (B)

#### `/.htaccess` (A):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

#### `/B/.htaccess` (B):

```
# BEGIN MainWP
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN MainWP` and `END MainWP` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END MainWP



# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /traveltour/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /traveltour/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN SSL

# END SSL
```

Comment: Security certs work on hostnames ie. `example.com` and `www.example.com`, not URL-paths, so whether it's (A) or (B) it shouldn't matter (except if there is some conflicting code in the WordPress source). You say it doesn't work - but what happens exactly? Does it resolve? Redirect loop? An error? Nothing?! If (A) redirects to HTTPS with WWW then so should (B) - it is the same domain isn't it? How have you separated (A) and (B)? (B) just looks like a subdirectory - so really there should be no separation anyway??

Comment: I need separated it because in each (A) and (B) use different theme for dev/debug purpose. I'm not sure it's possible to post a web link in here or not so I don't added it in my question. But if I tried load: (B) with http & non www, it's stay to http with www, or if I tried load: (B) with http & with www, it's stay same with no https. Some of code redirect (B) to (A) and made my link 404 not found, so I've removed it out.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting these directives? Do you have multiple `.htaccess` files (one for (A), one for (B))? Or is everything in one `.htaccess` in the root directory? Also, the order of the directives matters. These redirects would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file. Importantly, they must go _before_ the WordPress front-controller.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update this information. I have multiple .htaccess. One for (A) and one for (B). The (A) in root director: /public_html and the other available in: /public_html/B.

Comment: We'd need to see the contents of these two `.htaccess` files. So far, there's nothing to suggest why this does not work. As mentioned, the order of the directives matters. Further more, by default, any mod_rewrite directives in B will completely override any mod_rewrite directives in A (unless mod_rewrite inheritance is enabled - which arguably complicates matters). However, other modules (eg. mod_alias) are inherited, so there may be conflicts?

Comment: My htaccess file content: A-Htaccess: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ZgBRmGgx - B-Htaccess: https://www.codepile.net/pile/POaBJXYy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
> ```

This won't work if used in the `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory (site B) eg. `/traveltour/.htaccess`, since it will result in the user being redirected back to site A in the root. The captured backreference `$1` won't contain the subdirectory. You will need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead to use the full URL-path (as you are doing in the 3rd code block).

Also note that `SERVER_NAME` may not contain the desired value - depending on your system. By default, `SERVER_NAME` is the same as `HTTP_HOST` (the value of the `Host` HTTP request header, ie. the requested hostname), however, if `UseCanonicalName On` is set in the server config then this will instead be the value of the hostname set in the `ServerName` directive. Which could be either the non-www or www domain, or something else entirely (if you have multiple domains). So, without knowing your system, using `SERVER_NAME` here isn't necessarily a reliable/generalized solution.

For example, in `/B/.htaccess`, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Which is basically the same as your 3rd code block. The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required and should be omitted. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive either (which occurs *later* in the file - inside the WordPress code block).

In the root `/.htaccess` file (site A), you can use the same directives as above, OR the version with a capturing backreference - it does not matter in this context.

Note, however, this is only an HTTP to HTTPS redirect, it does not canonicalize the www subdomain. (This is usually handled by WordPress itself by setting the correct `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` values in `wp-config.php`.) To handle this in `.htaccess` you can modify the above rule to read:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This does assume you don't have other subdomains that need to be accessible, since everything is redirected to www.

If you want a "generalized" solution that doesn't explicitly mention the domain name (although this isn't necessarily the best option - depends on your system) then you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference matches the requested hostname less the `www.` prefix (if any).

Again, this will work in both the `/.htaccess` and `/B/.htaccess` files.

You should first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. And you will need to ensure your browser cache in clear before testing. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarify details, it's help me understanding a little of mod_rewrite in apache.